# Why can't I test the text of a text file?

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I've got a few methods which set the text within a text file.

I've set-up my jasmine tests to create the files with wrong values before I run my tests.

```
var gpioPath = 'tests/gpio-test/class/gpio';
//setup the filesystem with the exports path
fs.outputFileSync(gpioPath+'/export',0);
for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
    fs.outputFileSync(gpioPath+i+'/value',2,'utf-8');
    fs.outputFileSync(gpioPath+i+'/direction','none','utf-8');
}
```

Then, I run the methods which update the values in the files, and then I check that the files now have the correct values.

```
  expect(fs.readFileSync(gpioPath+'/export','utf-8')).toBeGreaterThan(0);

        var pin1d = fs.readFileSync(gpioPath+'1/direction','utf-8');
        var pin1v = fs.readFileSync(gpioPath+'1/value','utf-8');
        expect(pin1d).toBe('out');
        expect(pin1v).toBe(0);
```

For some reason, these tests are all failing. I get

```
'0' expected to be greater than '0'
```

But when I look in the file, I have a value of 6.

I've tried putting a `waits` before running the test, just in case the files hadn't been changed yet, but even with a 10 second wait this is still failing.

I don't get any errors from the fileWrite method, which is what is updating the data, and as I've said, I can see that the file is updated, so why don't my tests reflect this?

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFileSync(gpioPath+'/export','utf-8')` will return a string, so you are essentially doing `if (0 > '0')`, which is false.

if you need to test numbers, you need to parse it as a number:

```
expect(parseInt(fs.readFileSync(gpioPath+'/export','utf-8'), 10))
    .toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

This is assuming the file contains an ascii zero, and not a null byte.

Comment: You're right about the string to integer conversion, but I'm still not getting the updated values from the readFile. As I mentioned, I can see that the value is 5, but the test is showing `expected 0 to be greater than 0`. Strange.

Comment: @pedalpete What are you doing to see `5`? `cat`? A text editor?

Comment: @pedalpete Weird. Are you sure you are looking at the same file that is being modified by the script? The paths you have are relative to the current working directory, so they'll change location as you `cd` around.

Comment: yeah, I've checked that. This is why I thought it might be a timing issue, but I've put delays in, and I know it doesn't take 10 seconds to edit the file.

Comment: Also, if I change the setup so that the value the file starts with is greater than 0, than I get the test to pass. So I'm absolutely testing the right file response.